# Database structure - medicine usage

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design, persistence

I'm trying to make an Android app for tracking the users medicine usage.
The problem is I have very different setups for taking medicine.
The user is supposed to give information about when and how to take the medicine.

Some additional information like (before / after eating) could be stored in a separate table at the medicine description (e.g. it might not be necessary storing this together with the usage time).

Also, this is not the table with the information about when the user actually used it. (Here I have a simple table of the medicine_Id and the timestamp).

So the situation looks like this. The user sets the usage to:

- Aspirin - Breakfast and Dinner before eating
- Antibiotics - every 8 hours...

I thought I'd store these data in a database but I'm not sure how to do that. Or would it probably be better storing it in a different manner (e.g. shared preferences, JSON / XML, text file)?

Basically there seem to be the following types of "usage":

- n times a day (regularly, like every 8 hours)
- at certain meals (breakfast, lunch, dinner)
- daily based (once a day / every Monday and Saturday)

**Question is:**

What would be an appropriate solution for persisting these data (on an Android device)? 
And (if using SQLite) what would you suggest for the database scheme?

**----- EDIT -----**

Just to make things clear. **I don't need a description text for the user** when to take the medicine. 
**What I need is an information for setting an alarm according to the given settings**. So in the end I need a value I can match later like

```
(if currentTime == breakfastTime)
   ...
```

or maybe

```
(if medicine.takeAtBreakfast)
   ...
```

That renders String values that are describing the info for the user useless. First idea was boolean columns for the database for breakfast, lunch, dinner and the same for week days. But that seems a lot of wasted space.

Comment: What are you actually asking about?  Do you want a database schema, Java code, something else?  Your question seems a bit broad.

Comment: Well, first of all, the question is if that would work with a database. If so, the scheme would be amazing!

Comment: Hi Tobias, I attempted an answer below.  We can iterate on it until we reach something you find is usable.

Answer (score 3):

Medications are usually taken no more than a few times per day.  This may not always be the case, but it is probably safe to assume that this is the case most of the time.  In your description, the medication times were fairly well behaved, e.g. twice per day, every 8 hours, but in practice the regimen could be more complex than this.  In general, we should expect that a doctor could instruct a patient to take a medication a handful of times, across any points of time in the day.

With these assumptions in mind, we can consider the following table for taking medication:

```
regimen (id, subscription_id, medication_id, time_of_day, comment)
```

A given entry in this table would correspond to one prescription, one patient, one medication, and a given time of day.  For a prescription requiring more than one dose during the day, there would be a record for each dose.

The prescriptions table would record the drugs in a given Rx, along with the doses for each drug:

```
prescriptions (id, date, doctor_id, patient_id, medication_id, dose)
```

This is just a start, and you would need tables for medication, possibly several of them.  In addition, there could be a table for doctors and the relevant metadata.

**Edit:**

To handle a prescription which is once daily (i.e. any time during the day), we can set `time_of_day` to `NULL`.  For twice daily, we can use two records, each representing one dose.  We could use the comments column to indicate first dose, second dose, etc., or possibly add another column.

Comment: So that means I need a table for "during meals" another one "hourly based" another one "daily based" with the same schema and enter the different prescriptions each in the related table? I was afraid this might result in "fragmented" data set where it's not clear which data is available in which table.

Comment: @TobiasReich No, because each one of these times is simply one or more points in time.  Just have one table for medication scheduling.  I added a `comment` columns which could contain, for example, the text "at breakfast," or "second dose," etc.

Comment: What I don't understand is how "time of day" might work. After all, some are just daily, others at different times (i.e. meals). So what would be the information I put there?
If it would be for instance a table on a "per day" basis, I'd write an integer of the week day. For "meals" a similar solution like 1= breakfast, 2=lunch, ... would be possible. Still having a mixed data set seems to render this useless.

Answer (score 1):

Have A table with the kind of usages (times a day, meals). Then 
have in your intersection table a column amount which specifies the number of usages (eg. 3 daily, breakfast).

[image]

Comment: So that means, I have an extra table about the usage type. And another one about the usage times. I see StartDate and EndDate but how can I map this to e.g. "Breakfast" or "Monday and Wednesday"?

Comment: Startdate and enddate were just inpiration. As in the answer above you could consider my 'amount' column , the 'comment' column. No need to map all the subtypes and so on to tables. It would become very cumbersome very fast.

Comment: So but how could I store the different types of usage in these three rows?

Comment: In my example you can't. You just have your usage type (eg. meals) and in the amount column you would just enter text ("Breakfast and dinner"); This is a very simplistic approach to your problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is, I need the exact dates (so I can set an alarm). So a text "breakfast" is not usable for my case.